# What are data structures in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, data-structures

What are the data structures that we can use in Objective-C?

Answer (score 33):

`NSArray` is your standard array structure.

`NSDictionary` is a key-value "hash map"

`NSSet` is an unordered collection of unique objects.

Each of these is immutable (ie, once you create them, you can't change them).  If you need to modify them dynamically, then you'll use their mutable subclasses: `NSMutableArray`, `NSMutableSet`, etc.

For structures beyond this, check out the CHDataStructures framework, which has queues, stacks, trees, treaps, and a whole lot more:  http://cocoaheads.byu.edu/code/chdatastructures

Comment: Great answer, thanks Dave. @sukumar Y U NO Accept Answer?

Answer (score 5):

Objective-C is C, so it supports `struct` and the familiar C-language data types like int and char.

In addition there are special Objective-C classes.

You might want to take a look at [Apple's Objective-C book](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/ObjC.pdf).

Answer (score 2):

The following documents may help:

- [The Objective-C Programming Language](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/Introduction/Introduction.html)
- [Cocoa Fundamentals Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/Introduction/Introduction.html)